# Using DLRS to roll up to the Contact from an Opportunity

Tags: opportunity, contact, roll-up-summary, dlrs

I am attempting to roll up the total giving amount from the opportunity object onto the Contact record using DLRS. Attached is a screen shot of the rollup summary I built. I did not get any errors when saving it, deployed the trigger, and ran a calculate job. There were no errors returned in the log after running the job, however - only 0's or blanks were populated in my Aggregate Result Field, and I cannot figure out why.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :) [image]

Comment: The best resource for DLRS support is the dedicated [Community discussion group](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009O5pCAE).

Comment: I notice you have Calculation Mode set to User. Does the running user have rights to see all Opportunities in your org? Does the behavior change if you configure System mode?

Comment: Yes, as of now running users have the right to see all opportunities. My other DLRS are all configured to User mode, but I will try switching it to System and see if that changes anything!

Comment: I also just tried changing the field type on my field to aggregate to (it was number and I changed it to currency) to see if that made a difference, but no luck....

Comment: Are you sure the `cv__Contact__c` field is non-null on your Opportunities? That won't include Opportunity Contact Roles.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'non-null'. We are only looking to roll up Hard Credit amounts, so we do not need contact roles...however it is my understanding that the Opportunity Contact Role object does not work with DLRS because Salesforce does not allow triggers to be used on that object? Is that correct?